# What is the difference between Matrix<Depth> and McvMat in Emgu cv?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

What is the difference between Matrix and McvMat in Emgu cv? How do I create a McvMat?

Answer (score 1):

A `Matrix` is a wrapper to `cvMat` of OpenCV and `MCvMat` is structure format of this. `Matrix` provide more functionality over `MCvMat`

```
Matrix<int> r = new Matrix<int>(2, 3);
MCvMat m = r.MCvMat;
```

For detail > [Emgu.CV.Matrix](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/ec1c8c3f-a99c-a082-e794-bb74db961c60.htm)